# Show template's code with @Storybook/addon-docs

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

I'm documenting my components in Storybook. I added `@storybook/addon-docs` and in *.stories.ts I defined story like this:

```
export const Button = () => ({
  template: '<button class="button">Delete</button>',
});
```

Button with styling is shown correctly, but when someone clicks "Show code", it shows story's code, not just the template.

```
() => ({
  template: '<button class="button button-danger">Delete</button>'
})
```

Is it possible to configure, that "Show code" shows template, not whole story?

Answer (score 0):

Try commenting, docs source

```
//Connect below line from .stories.js
parameters: {
 docs: {
  source: {
    type: 'code'
  }
 }
}
```